# Magento2: An error has happened during application run

Tags: magento2

I created in backend multi language on different website.

example:

- mainwebsite.pl
- additionalwebsite.com

on .pl everything work but when I enter .com then:

```
An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details. Could not write error message to log. Please use developer mode to see the message.
```

Comment: have you checked the log ?

Comment: [2019-03-22 14:18:04] main.CRITICAL: No such entity. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity. at /home/zabezcen/domains/zabezcen.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:80)"} []
[2019-03-22 14:18:21] main.CRITICAL: No such entity. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity. at /home/zabezcen/domains/zabezcen.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:80)"} []